# Excel Application.OnTime causing glitchy behavior any alternative?

Tags: excel, vba

After running Application.OnTime every 10 seconds eventually Excel will get extremely glitchy and force me to double click in a cell to force it to refresh among other seemingly random behavior. Is there any alternative needed to run a task often while still allowing the EXCEL GUI to remain responsive or reliable?

To test this I literally run a simple VBA function to modify a few cells on multiple computers and the issue eventually persists, in a few minutes or hours, or instantly if ran every 5 seconds.

Some pseudo code:

```
Foo(){
wait 10 seconds (non blocking)
Foo()
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which shows how, starting with a blank workbook, someone else can reproduce this problem. My guess is that there is something important about your situation that you haven't mentioned. Having said that, a cheap fix might be to include a `DoEvents` in the macro.

Comment: @JohnColeman I feel like I have asked many variations of this question before, but it is literally true... if you simply write to cells with Application.OnTime for a long enough period of time the GUI completely locks up... it's literally as simple as it can get, DoEvents doesn't even respond, I have tried minimizing and maximizing Excel programmatically etc etc, it is pretty crazy and appears to just be a glitch with Excel being unable to write back and forth between the script without locking up. The only solution is manually minimize maximize and double click in cell and that works 50%...

Comment: @JohnColeman when I say you can do literally anything (edit cells within a 10 second interval etc) I meant it, but I will try to put together a minimal example for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Timer at the module level. A simple Timer, but taking care of all necessary variable setting. Otherwise, Excel can crush. You can also create a very stable Timer but it is a whole project behind such an idea. Anyhow, I can use such a Timer without problems in my projects. What is nice is the fact that once started **the Timer works even in cell edit mode**...
Create a standard module (I all the time name it "Timer_module") with the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long

Private TimerID As LongPtr
Private xTimer As Long, howMany As Long


Sub StartTimer(TimerSeconds As Long, howManyTimes As Long)
    howMany = howManyTimes
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000, AddressOf T_Pr)
End Sub
Sub StopTimer()
       On Error Resume Next
       KillTimer 0, TimerID
       xTimer = 0
End Sub
Sub T_Pr(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
            ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)
      xTimer = xTimer + 1:  Debug.Print xTimer, Now
      DoEvents
      If xTimer = howMany Then StopTimer: Debug.Print "Timer stopped: " & Now
End Sub
```

In another module the Timer can be simple called like in the next code:

```
Sub testTimeer()
  StartTimer 2, 4
End Sub
```

Were the first parameters means the number of seconds which must path until the timer function will do something. The code can be easily adapted to work for milliseconds. The second parameter means the number of timer function runs after the timer is stopped. It is just an example an it can be easily adapted in order to fulfill your need. So you can set it to act just once, you can call `StopTimer()' procedure whenever you need (from a loop, for instance) and so on...

P.S. Such a timer can be easily linked to a form. You have to take care of `TimerID` definition. It should be the form handle. For instance, in this way:

```
TimerID = GetActiveWindow
```

This piece of code must be part of the form initialize event and of course `TimerID` must be **a `Public` declared variable**...
And you must take care that when the Timer runs all the rest of the running code to be very stable and have error handlers able to stop Timer in case of errors.

Comment: Can you slightly adapt this to recursively run foo() forever every 10 seconds while allowing Excel to function? Then I will mark as the answer, even if it doesn't resolve the Excel lockup problem it's a pretty neat alternative.

Comment: @CodeCamper: I would be able to do that if you will post a piece of code to adapt. I only presented a solution in order to build a Timer to use it according to your need. In fact, the "recursive" function is not a solution, I think. You can do your job waiting for "something" in a loop and stopping the Timer when the need has been fulfilled. Calling the `StopTimer()' function as I mentioned... Do you have such piece of code which is not top secret, as you had to do in order to make us better understand your need?. :-)

Comment: The need will never be fulfilled. It is just a function to run every 10 seconds until the computer explodes or restarts. Let's say foo() just adds two numbers together every 10 seconds forever. For the purposes of your answer though a blank foo() function will be sufficient I think to answer my question as it stands. `running Application.OnTime every 10 seconds eventually [...]` If I have the same issues using your procedure then I will post as a separate question for you to answer.

Comment: @CodeCamper: I afraid you did not understand the code... The "code" will run for as many seconds (milliseconds) you want. The meaning of its first parameter was clearly explained, I think. This is a little much more then your `OnTime`. Without disturbing your Excel, even in edit mode. If you are not able to understand the way of working, why don't you post your code to be adapted it in the way to use it according to your need. Your need is abstract in this very moment. You are just unsatisfied about `OnTime`...

Comment: @CodeCamper: This code/Timer **runs forever and does what you need if you understand how to use it**! but YOU must tell it what to check and with which frequency...

Comment: The behavior of `Application.OnTime` is you specify a time delay and the name of the function you want to run after that set of time, so with simple recursion you can do A1 += 1 for example and run `Application.OnTime` again and again. Are you saying I should just use your StartTimer 10,1 at the end of the function just before calling Foo()? I added the pseudocode to my original question. I just think it would be helpful to provide an example with Foo() of how exactly to use that second parameter / or just simply run every 10 seconds.

Comment: FaneDuru, sorry my question was not clear, your code is very helpful, please see the edit I made with the simple pseudocode, I will promptly mark this as the answer once you adapt it to simply do that pseudocode example. I'm just asking for it to be clarified in a way where someone else who would want to substitute OnTime (simple seconds loop) could drop in this function you kindly provided.

Comment: My Timer example only counts `xTimer ` variable in order to make you understand that it works! If you do not understand that instead of that you must call your function I am afraid we are loosing time. I wish you a good day!

Comment: Yes, my question was a little wordy, but I think if you read it carefully you will see that is what I was asking for... if you want me to readopt the code you provided and mark it as a separate answer I can... I was just asking you to do it so I could mark yours as an answer anyone could see and easily use because you were already pretty comprehensive.

Comment: @CodeCamper: Are you talking about your `Foo()` function like being a VBA one? Do you need a solution for a C# project?

Comment: It would be a VBA one, not a C# one, by recursion I mean running a seperate VBA function every 10 seconds, hence being a great substitute for the OnTime function as per the Foo example.

Comment: @CodeCamper: Strictly not necessarily!  Do you have a real need to be expressed in a piece of code, or you just want to learn something  not knowing how to put the problem? And I know very well what recursion means.

Comment: This is just a generic learning question as I have implemented OnTime for many different things and always run into the same performance issues (when using it to to loop a function forever or too quickly) which is why I asked for an alternative, but if you want a concrete example, let's say Foo is adding to a cell every 10 seconds, checking for certain changes to the sheet every 10 seconds... If I wanted to implement something like this in C# it would be a lot easier and less problems, but definitely not relevant to my question.

Comment: @CodeCamper: So, just replace `xTimer = xTimer + 1:  Debug.Print xTimer, Now` with your function name to be called and comment `If xTimer = howMany Then StopTimer: Debug.Print "Timer stopped: " & Now` line. Then call `StartTimer 10, 0`. The second parameter can be any long value. It will not be taken in consideration. This code will run forever, or until you will call `StopTimer'.